# Spring, Hibernate, EntityManager and class inheritance

Tags: hibernate, spring, entitymanager, hibernate-entitymanager

I'm pretty much new to Spring & Hibernate. In our team, we are building a web application using Struts 2 for the presentation layer, with Spring 3 and Hibernate 3 (with Annotations) underneath. We are still debating on whether to use DAOs or not and `Session`'s or `EntityManager`'s for CRUD operations. Setting aside the question of which is better than the other, I ran into another problem using `EntityManager`.

My goal is to create an abstract (generic) `Service` which will expose 4 basic operations: save, delete, find by ID and find all by class. Other services will inherit from this and just implement custom finds or updates (this may change in the future). Problem is, I'm unsure where to put the annotated `EntityManager`. I understand that if I call save() in a service from my `Action`, i.e. Bob, which inherits the `save()` from the Person parent `Service`, the system will fail to inject the `EntityManager` because the Service Person has not been called and the `@PersistenceContext` annotation was not parsed.

Is there a way around this problem? I'd like to use inheritance for my services because that would reduce the amount of code needed for simple operations.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://blog.springsource.com/2006/08/07/using-jpa-in-spring-without-referencing-spring/) may be helpful.

If you end up using `Session` objects you'll want to look into [HibernateDaoSupport](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/HibernateDaoSupport.html) which will function nicely as base class for your generic service class.